# Passing values by reference into void function

Tags: c++, function, void

I want to create a program that asks the user for a year, month and day. It checks each value against set criteria using one void function to carry out the validation against a set range. eg. Year must be > 1970 and < 2020.

The same function is meant to be used for validating month and day range also.

I have just started with the year but am having trouble with passing values into the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

//declare function
void get_data();

int main()
{
//local variable declaration    
int input;
int criteria_1 = 1970;
int criteria_2 = 2020;

// ask for input and store
cout << "Enter the year: ";
cin >> input;

//call the function to validate the number    
get_data(input, criteria_1, criteria_2);

return 0;
}

//define function
void get_data(int x, int y, int z)
{
// set variable for what is being inputted
int input;

//repeat asking user for input until a valid value is entered
while (x <= y||x >= z){
    cout << "The valid range is >=" + y;
    cin >> x;
    input = x;
}
//display output on screen
cout << input << endl;

//reset variable for what was inputted 
input = 0;

return;
}
```

Can you please give me some guidance? I am very new to this. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to "reset" local variables when a function returns – every function invocation has its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `input` variable declared `main` to be affected by the subsequent call to `get_data(input, criteria_1, criteria_2)` you have to declare the corresponding variable as an lvalue reference by using an ampersand (&), like so:

```
void get_data(int &x, int y, int z)
```

Also, you have to remove the declaration of `input` from `get_data` (it'd be a new variable and NOT the same as the one declared in `main`) and write

```
x = 0;
```

at the end of the function. When calling `get_data(input, criteria_1, criteria_2)`, `x` inside the function is "hard-wired" to the passed in variable `input` and any assignments done to `x` are done to `input`.

Comment: thanks Matthias. I have added the criteria as per your comments. When i run the program, i can enter the date but there is no validation. I get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

While declaring you need to get the signature right. It should be

```
void get_data(int, int, int);
```

Remember, C++ allows overloading of functions. So it is very important to get the signature right.